# How can i use variable outside switch case within Java switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have variables defined outside switch and used them within switch case. I want to run a code that will take value of any switch case. This code will be outside switch. I tried but i got error like STATEMENT UNREACHABLE.

Here what i've tried :

```
BigDecimal firstvalue, secondvalue, calculation;


button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


firstvalue =  new BigDecimal("45");
secondvalue = new BigDecimal("23");



switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()){

case 0:
{
calculation = firstvalue.multiply(secondvalue);                      
break;
}
case 1:
{
calculation = firstvalue.add(secondvalue);
break;
}
case 2:
{
calculation = firstvalue.subtract(secondvalue);
break;
}

// Any of above case will apply for calculation 
// Then this program that is outside switch should run
   
calculation.multiply(new BigDecimal("30"));
               

}
}
});
```

Comment: What line produces this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code of your `java` file and add the complete error message you get to your question. Also fix the indentation of your source code so it is easier to see which block starts and ends where.

Comment: Error is not reproducible, please provide full snippet.

Comment: This is the complete code. In this code first java will check which option is selected and perform the case accordingly. For example if user selects first option it will run case 0 where it will do multiplication of first and second value and then Calculation variable will be multiplied with 30. Now the error is that `calculation.multiply(new BigDecimal("30"));` is unreachable statement .  ?????

Comment: Where should i share the complete code ? @Giorgi Tsiklauri

Comment: Here, as a [mcve]

Comment: That's already done in question . @daniu

Comment: Copy your code, paste it into an editor, compile it. I haven't tried, but there's not even a `class ` definition, so I doubt it'll compile.

Comment: I have class, but didn't shared. `public class mainpage extends AppCompatActivity { //here the above is  }`

Answer (score 1):

You have written the code line calculation.multiply(new BigDecimal("30")) inside the switch statement itself. So it is part of case 2.

But since you are breaking before the line, that code line is never reached (even for case2). You should really follow indentations as stated in comments to identify such errors easily.

Answer (score 0):

`calculation` is assigned inside the switch, but it is defined outside the switch (before the switch starts). This means you can use it after the switch.

All you need to do is move `calculation.multiply` one line down, after one of the `}`

It might be a good thing to assign a default value to calculation, either where it is defined, or using a "default" clause in your switch